# creating custom mount point in / for a file system

Tags: filesystems, fstab

If I want to mount a file system at `/myname` is it possible by just editing **fstab** file?
Or should I do more to be safer?

Is any other way to do it, or its not a good idea to do?

Comment: No offense to ctt, but I don't understand why you made his answer the accepted answer when pradeepchhetri's answer came earlier and is way, way better.

Comment: It may have been chosen because it answered the question. The other post didn't explain whether editing the fstab was a suitable option (the question posed).  It just presented more options.

Comment: @gparent ctt is right

Comment: Well, the other answer literally tells you to edit /etc/fstab but I guess that isn't enough. Oh well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it.  By editing the fstab file, you'll have options to maintain the mount across reboot.  Also, you'll be able to ask mount to simply `mount /myname` and it'll work out.

So to answer your question, definitely yes.

Answer (score 4):

You want that partition with a different file system to be mounted in Linux. So there can be two cases:

**1. If the partition is to be mounted in every boot:**

You have to create an empty directory where you want to mount that file-system. Suppose I want to mount a windows partition(/dev/sda1) to `/myname`, then i have to create an empty directory `/myname`

`$ sudo mkdir /myname`

Now you have to open `/etc/fstab` file and add the entry for the file-system.

`$ sudo vi /etc/fstab`

Add the following line to the file:

`/dev/sda1    /myname    ntfs    defaults    0    0`

Now since you have changed /etc/fstab file, you have to make the kernel to read the file to mount the entry which you have added just now.

`$ sudo mount -a`

**2. If the partition is to be mounted for this time only, but not for every boot:**

You can use `mount` command to tell it to mount the partition:

`$ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /myname`

Comment: I know this procedure but I want to mount the fs at `/myname` like `/pahnin`

Comment: @pahnin: There won't be any problem even if you want to mount it in a directory like /myname. There are other method also by which you can do this. If you want I can edit my answer with those also but you have to tell me the Linux distro which you are using

Comment: linux mint debian edition